# Merge duplicates and remove the oldest

Tags: mongodb, merge, mapreduce, updates

I have a collection where there are some duplicate documents. In example:

First document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56f3d7cc1de31cb20c08ae6b"),
    "AddedDate" : ISODate("2016-05-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "Place": "THISPLACE",
    "PresentInDB" : [ 
        {
            "InDB" : ISODate("2016-05-01T00:00:00.000Z")
        }
     ],
    "Checked" : [],
    "Link": "http://www.mylink.com/first/84358"
}
```

Second document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("577740526c1e542904725238"),
    "AddedDate" : ISODate("2016-05-02T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "Place": "THISPLACE",
    "PresentInDB" : [ 
        {
            "InDB" : ISODate("2016-05-02T00:00:00.000Z")
        },
        {
            "InDB" : ISODate("2016-05-03T00:00:00.000Z")
        }
     ],
    "Checked" : [
        {
            "Done" : ISODate("2016-05-02T00:00:00.000Z")
        },
    ],
    "Link": "http://www.mylink.com/second/84358"
}
```

`Link` field contains same sequense of numbers in both documents, `84358`.

So I would like to achieve those steps:

1. Loop over each document in the collection.
2. Match the number sequence in each document in the `Link` field (i.e. `84358` above) and if there are **several** documents in
   collection that have that sequence in the `Link` field. And also if `Place` field match in both documents:
3. Merge `PresentInDB` and `Checked` fields - > merge `PresentInDB` and `Checked` fields by adding array values from the newest document (by date in `AddedDate`
   field) to the oldest document.
4. Remove the newest document.

How could I achieve such a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MongoDB 3.3.6 release is introduced a `$split` operator for dealing with strings in aggregation framework ([Jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6773)). Before this release you only could solve this with a map/reduce solution.

**After MongoDB 3.3.6 release: Aggregation framework solution**

```
db.duplicatedCollection.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $project: {
        _id : 1,
        AddedDate : 1,
        Place : 1,
        PresentInDB : 1,
        Checked : 1,
        Link : 1,
        sequenceNumber: { $arrayElemAt: [ {$split: ["$Link", "/"]}, -1 ]},
      }
    }, 
    {
      $sort: { AddedDate: 1 }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id : {
          sequenceNumber : "$sequenceNumber",
          Place : "$Place"
        },
        id : { $first: "$_id"},
        AddedDate: { $first: "$AddedDate" },
        Place :  { $first: "$Place" },
        PresentInDB: {
          $push: '$PresentInDB'
        },
        Checked: {
          $push: '$Checked'
        },
        Link: { $first: "$Link"}
      }
    }, 
   {
      $unwind: "$PresentInDB"
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path : "$PresentInDB",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
      }    
    },
    {
      $unwind: "$Checked"
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
        path : "$Checked",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
      }
    },    
    {
      $group: {
        _id : "$id",
        AddedDate: { $first: "$AddedDate" },        
        Place :  { $first: "$Place" },
        PresentInDB : {
          $addToSet: '$PresentInDB'
        },
        Checked : {
          $addToSet: '$Checked'
        },        
        Link: { $first: "$Link"}
      }
    },  
    {
      $out: "duplicatedCollection"
    }
  ]
);
```

**Before MongoDB 3.3.6 release: Map/Reduce solution**

Map Function:

```
var mapFunction = function() {
    var linkArray = this.Link.split("/");
    var sequenceNumber = linkArray[linkArray.length - 1];

    var keyDoc = { 
       place : this.Place,
       sequenceNumber: sequenceNumber, 
    };

    emit(keyDoc, this);
};
```

Reduce Function:

```
var reduceFunction = function(key, values) {   
    var reducedDoc = {};
    reducedDoc._id = values[0]._id;
    reducedDoc.AddedDate = values[0].AddedDate;
    reducedDoc.Link = values[0].Link;
    reducedDoc.PresentInDB = [];
    reducedDoc.Checked = [];

    var presentInDbMillisArray = [];
    var checkedMillisArray = [];        

    values.forEach(function(doc) {
        if (reducedDoc.AddedDate < doc.AddedDate) {
            reducedDoc._id = doc._id;
            reducedDoc.AddedDate = doc.AddedDate;
            reducedDoc.Link = doc.Link;
        } 

        // PresentInDB field merge
        doc.PresentInDB.forEach(function(presentInDBElem) {
            var millis = presentInDBElem.InDB.getTime();
            if (!Array.contains(presentInDbMillisArray, millis)) { 
                reducedDoc.PresentInDB.push(presentInDBElem);
                presentInDbMillisArray.push(millis);
            }
        });

        // same here with Checked field
        doc.Checked.forEach(function(checkedElem) {
            var millis = checkedElem.Done.getTime();
            if (!Array.contains(checkedMillisArray, millis)) { 
                reducedDoc.Checked.push(checkedElem);
                checkedMillisArray.push(millis);
            }
        });
    });
    return reducedDoc;
};
```

Map/Reduce:

```
db.duplicatedCollection.mapReduce(
    mapFunction,
    reduceFunction,
    { 
        "out": "duplicatedCollection"
    }
);
```

Unwrap the value from the map/reduce returned documents:

```
   db.duplicatedCollection.find(
    {
        value : {
            $exists: true 
        }
    }
    ).forEach(function(doc) {
        db.duplicatedCollection.insert(doc.value);
        db.duplicatedCollection.remove({_id : doc._id});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single [`aggregation`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) query to do that :

```
db.device.aggregate([{
    "$unwind": "$PresentInDB"
}, {
    "$match": {
        "Link": /84358/
    }
}, {
    "$sort": {
        "AddedDate": 1
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
        _id: 0,
        PresentInDB: {
            $addToSet: '$PresentInDB'
        },
        AddedDate: {
            $first: "$AddedDate"
        },
        id: {
            $first: "$_id"
        },
        Link: {
            $first: "$Link"
        }
    }
}, {
    $out: "documents"
}])
```

- `$unwind` your array to work on it
- `$match` your id (here containing 84358)
- `$sort` by ascending date
- `$group` with :

  - a `$addToSet` to merge all your `PresentInDB` into one single array without duplicates
  - a `$first` for each field to keep. Keeping the first means you only want the older one since we previously sorted by ascending date
- `$out` will save the results to a new collection called `documents` here

Comment: Thanks, but I did update the question, seems like the update did not happen before now... I have two fields to merge `PresentInDB`and `Checked` fields. How could I do that with aggregate?

Comment: I also need to `DROP` the newest duplicate document from this collection, not add to new collection!

Comment: And also, there are several duplicates, not only `"Link": /84358/`